# Intellij not recognising environment variable in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, environment-variables, pom.xml

In my maven project, I have a dependency on a jar that will be present in a certain location within system and not in a repository. So, I'm using SystemPath for the dependency in pom.xml. But the systemPath is dependent on a environment variable. But Intellij is not recognising the environment variable. I even tried setting the path using

```
<systemPath>${HOME}/dir1/dir2/abc.jar</systemPath>
```

But Intellij is not even recognising the $HOME variable. But if I give the absolute path like

```
<systemPath>/Users/myuser/dir1/dir2/abc.jar</systemPath>
```

Intellij is picking it up properly. Any idea how to resolve this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment Variables can be referred in pom.xml using 'env.' prefix.

Please refer to [Maven properties](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html)

For example,

```
env.PATH
```

Contains the current PATH in which Maven is running. The PATH contains a list of directories used to locate executable scripts and programs.